# Itreate through two hashmaps to find duplicate key values

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I have created two hashmaps:

```
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Each map takes in values from text files on my PC

I have found a way to find duplicates in both of the maps:

```
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(map1.keySet());
    s.retainAll(map2.keySet());
    System.out.println("Duplicates" + s);
```

The overall program will do the following:

Place the duplicates in a separate hashmap

**For example:**

map1 contains:

- 1234,LID4321
- 918,LID6677
- 945, LID8765

map2 contains:

- 1234,LID1234
- 918,LID5242
- 2322,LID8837
- 7777,LID9871

*The end result would be:*

And mapDuplicates will contain the duplicates:

- 1234,LID4321
- 918,LID6677
- 1234,LID1234
- 918,LID5242

**The keys are equal, therefore they are duplicates**

Comment: `map1.keySet().removeAll(s.keySet())` should work.

Comment: I get the following error when I use this code:  `the method keySet() is undefined for the type Set<string>`

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your use of `retainAll` is the correct way to find the appropriate keys. You can easily iterate over that set and the two maps to get hold of the corresponding values. Would you like to have a single `map` where each key corresponds to a pair of values?

Comment: @Alex Hall In terms of your response I think I'm looking to "iterate over that set and the two maps to get hold of the corresponding values". For example I need to retain the values for key 1234 in map1 and map2

Comment: So what's wrong? You don't know how to iterate over a set? Get values from a map?

Comment: @AlexHall thanks for getting back to me. At the moment my `retainAll` just gives the keys that are duplicate (current result is `1234, 918`). But I need both the keys and values of all duplicate values, my example `mapDuplicates` is what I need in the end result. I'm new to hashmaps, so if I'm not being clear I apologise

Comment: Your representation of `mapDuplicates` doesn't make sense because it suggests that the same key should appear twice, once with each value. Maps can't have duplicate values, hence the method `keySet`. You can store them as pairs in a list/array, or a map from unique keys to pairs of values. In any case it is still not clear what you are having trouble with. Do you know how to iterate over a set? Do you know how to put values in a map and how to retrieve them by key? If so, then you should be able to perform this task. Show some code and explain why it's not working.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks for the response. Maybe I should just set out what I'm trying to achieve. The key and value are user ids(1234) and logon ids(LID1234), respectively, for a system. The hashmaps will consist of user ids and logons ids from two different systems. However some users have two logon ids and I need to identify these users. So if user 1234 has a logon id in both hashmaps I want to print out both of those logon ids(LID1234 and LID 4321). If this was two arrays I would know to use for loops to iterate through both arrays and print the duplicates in both arrays.

Comment: "I need to identify these users." - you've done that, it's the set `s`. "So if user 1234 has a logon id in both hashmaps I want to print out both of those logon ids(LID1234 and LID 4321)." Surely you can solve that problem? If you have a hashmap and a key I assume you know how to get the value. If you have two hashmaps just do the same thing twice.

Comment: @AlexHall That probably should have been my original question, so thank you. I don't know how to retrieve the values, I can display the keys but not the values.

Comment: Have you looked through a tutorial on java maps? Getting a value given a key is the most basic operation. Without it maps would be utterly useless.

Comment: @AlexHall I understand that you are probably seriously frustrated at this stage so I thank you for staying with this thread. I think its this piece of code: `String val=map1.get();` I just don't know what to pass as a parameter to retrieve the value.

Comment: The `get` method is correct. Surely the tutorial or API reference you are looking at says what the parameter should be. Copy paste some text from wherever `get` is mentioned.

Comment: @AlexHall the get method in the example contains a number to reference the key. [link] http://beginnersbook.com/2014/08/hashmap-get-value-from-key-example/

Comment: The number *is* the key. The point is that `get` takes a key. You have plenty of keys.

Comment: @AlexHall I thought it would have been something like this  `Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(map.keySet());
     s.retainAll(map2.keySet());
     String val = map.get(s);
     
     System.out.println("Duplicates 1 " + s + val + "\r\n ");`

Comment: `get` takes in a single key (a `String`) and returns a single value. It cannot handle a collection of keys such as `s` which is a `Set<String>`. You have to pass a single key at a time from `s`.

Comment: @AlexHall so the main question here is how do I get the `get`method the return the values of the keys retained in `retainAll`. That is ultimately what I need

Comment: By calling `get` once for each key in `s`.

Comment: @AlexHall Are the values in `s` not all contained in one big `String`? How do I isolate each key?

Comment: `s` is a `Set`, which is a `Collection`. The other main `Collection` is a `List`. `Collection`s are similar to arrays in the sense that they store multiple values in a single variable, but the values are kept separate. You should have looked at a tutorial on sets but I've tortured you enough. The best way to iterate over a set is with a 'foreach' (or 'enhanced for') loop which looks like this: `for (String key : s) { /* do something with 'key' */ }`.

Comment: @AlexHall thank you it works now, the torture will only improve my skills. I kept trying to find a website of how that type of foreach( I didn't even know it was called a foreach) loop works. I have never used a foreach loop before, is it exclusively used in hashmaps/hashsets?

Comment: It's for any `Iterable` or array. Google "java foreach" and it'll explain what's going on. It's fancy syntax to avoid calling the `iterator` method. The info you wanted should have been found in a tutorial on java sets. The thing to google was "java iterate set".

Comment: @AlexHall appreciate all you help